# What it means to look like ' a bit of a chop'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, british-english

From [dnaindia](http://www.dnaindia.com/sport/report-chris-gayle-turns-on-critics-says-sexist-comments-was-just-a-little-fun-2215768):

> Chappell and Flintoff, former captains of Australia and England respectively, were among those to criticise Gayle's conduct.
>
> But Gayle, in an extract from his autobiography published in The Times on Monday, said of his remarks during the Melbourne Renegades' match against Hobart Hurricanes: "I meant it as a joke. I meant it as a little fun. I didn't mean to be disrespectful and I didn't mean it to be taken serious."
>
> Flintoff responded on Twitter by saying Gayle had made himself look a "**bit of a chop**".
>
> But Gayle, in his autobiography, said: "The only chop Freddie (Flintoff) knows is when he used to bowl short to me and I would chop him past backward point for four."

[More to read](http://www.news18.com/cricketnext/news/bbl-franchise-renegades-not-to-sign-gayle-after-fresh-sexism-row-1247268.html).

Comment: Hint: How can a pork chop carry on?

Comment: This is tagged british-english, but is it maybe indian-english?  (Honestly, I have no idea.  Athletics is Greek to me, and I can't even figure out what sport they're talking about.  Cricket? Football?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what a pork chop is?

> A chop is a small flat piece of meat usually  cut from a sheep or a pig.

But perhaps you don't know that this piece of meat is usually heavily **beaten** from both sides with a help of a special metal hammer to make it soft.
The main character of your question is a cricketer, who was interviewed by a woman journalist. His behaviour was considered to be disrespectful and he was **"beaten"** by his colleagues on the net. That's why one of them called the cricket player **"a bit of a chop"**.There's also a saying 
"carrying on like a pork chop at a Jewish wedding" meaning "a person exhibiting inappropriate behaviour".

The other meaning of *chop* is

> to strike (a ball) with a short heavy blow, as if cutting at something.

There's such a strike in cricket and Gayle (our hero) tried to make a joke answering his colleague.

Comment: He meant Andrew looks like an attacker?

Comment: He meant "a cricket player knows only one meaning of the word "chop",that is a strike which gives you a maximum score."

Comment: And F. meant his inappropriate behaviour.

Comment: A chop is unlikely to come from a ship, a sheep is far more likely in that quote. In the UK lamb chops from younger sheep are popular.